# NodeJS socket on connection is not working

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

`socket.emit()` is working fine with callback function, but `socket.on()` is not invoking.

```
socket.on('connect', () => {      
    socket.emit(USER_STATUS_UPDATE, { user, status: 'online' }, console.log(`*********CALL`));

    socket.on(USER_STATUS_UPDATE, (userstatus) => {
          console.debug("USER_STATUS_UPDATE",userstatus);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Socket.on triggers when socket messages are emitted from the other parties, not when you emit them from the same party.

Server:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(80);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('request', /* */); // emit an event to the socket
  io.emit('broadcast', /* */); // emit an event to all connected sockets
  socket.on('reply', function(){ /* */ }); // listen to the event
});
```

Client:

```
  const socket = io('http://localhost/');
  socket.on('connect', function () {

    socket.on('request', function (msg) {
      socket.emit('reply', 'hi'); 
    });

    socket.on('broadcast', function (msg) {
      console.log(msg); 
    });

  });
```

Comment: this calls fine 
```socket.on(USER_STATUS_UPDATE, console.log('hi'));```


but below code not working
``` socket.on(USER_STATUS_UPDATE, (userstatus) => {
          console.debug("USER_STATUS_UPDATE", userstatus);
    });```

Comment: If you want that I improve my response further, put the server code in your answer.